# Как получить URL открытой вкладки?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Используется: **c#**, **webdriver**, **selenium**.

**СЦЕНАРИЙ**

1. **КОД.** Открывает Браузер Хром
2. **ЧЕЛОВЕК.** Открывает три вкладки

   - Вкладка 1 - Сайт 1;
   - Вкладка 2 - Сайт 2;
   - Вкладка 3 - Сайт 3;
3. **ЧЕЛОВЕК.** Переходит (активирует) на Вкладку 2;

**ВОПРОС**

1. Как по нажатии на button1 вывести в labe1 URL Сайта 2?

Comment: Вроде бы никак. Вы можете получить текущий урл вкладки, на которой находиться селениум, но то, что человек будет перелистывать вкладки, селениум об этом никак не узнает.

Answer (score 1):

В обработчик нажатия кнопки добавьте:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]); // переключаем драйвер на 2 вкладку
label1.Text = driver.Url; // получаем текущий URL активной вкладки
```

Либо так:

```
label1.Text = driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles[1]).Url;
```

Comment: Как я понял, ему надо знать вкладку, на которую человек перешел вручную. Т.е. такой код не сработает, если человек выбрал 3, 4,5,....100 вкладку

Comment: @AndrewBystrov не в курсе, в вопросе такой информации нет, я написал конкретное решение конкретного вопроса "Как по нажатии на button1 вывести в labe1 URL Сайта 2?"

Comment: ну как же нет. Он описал по шагам что сделал человек и после этого надо вывести урл с сайта2, т.к. челове на нее перешел. Или я не прав?

Comment: Суть ясна.

Я правильно понял, что данным кодом происходит только обращение к вкладке, а по факту она получается не "нажата"?


Т.е. если рассматривать следующий сценарий: 
1. КОД. Открывает Браузер Хром
2. ЧЕЛОВЕК. Открывает три вкладки
Вкладка 1 - Сайт 1;
Вкладка 2 - Сайт 2;
Вкладка 3 - Сайт 3;
3. ЧЕЛОВЕК. Нажимает кнопку. button1.
Необходимые данные для выполнения следующего пункта(п.4) будут браться из TextBox
4. КОД. Переходит (активирует) на Вкладку 2;

ВОПРОС (ВАР. 2) Как по нажатии на button1 вывести в labe1 URL Сайта 2?